# Как поменять местами 0 и 1 в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, системы-счисления

Решил написать свою функцию для перевода числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную. На положительных числах все норм, но чтобы разобраться с отрицательными нужно после деления поменять местами нули и единицы в полученной строке, но я не знаю как (пробовал метод replace, но он заменяет только что то одно, то есть либо нули на единицы либо наоборот)

Вот код:

```
def decimal_to_binary(number):
    final = ''
    number_positive = abs(number)
    while number_positive not in (0, -1):
        final += str(number_positive % 2)
        number_positive //= 2
    return (final.replace('0', '1'))[::-1] + '1' if number < 0 else final[::-1]
```

Comment: ''.join( ['1' if x=='0' else '0' for x in final[::-1] ] )

Comment: если не путаю , то string translate() тоже подойдёт

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
final.translate({ord("0"): "1", 
                 ord("1"): "0"})
```

или

```
final.translate(str.maketrans("01", "10"))
```

---

*Объяснение:*

В первом случае мы прямо задаваем переводную таблицу-словарь, ключами которого должны быть *порядковые номера символов (в системе Юникод)*, которые мы хотим заменить.

Во втором случае мы переводную таблицу создаем методом `.maketrans()` с двумя параметрами-строками *одинаковой длины*, что значит графически вот что:

```
"01" 
 ↓↓
"10"
```

т.е. все нули заменить на единицы и все единицы заменить на нули.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще сделать:

```
print(bin(42))
```

Своя функция:

```
def decimal_to_binary(number):
    return bin(number)

print(decimal_to_binary(42))
```

Comment: противоречит ''Решил написать свою функцию для перевода числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную. ''

Comment: @Интик исправил

Comment: @dimon lol. Ну тоже вариант, конечно.